# New to programming, inquiry

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner (Third Edition) and have unfortunately run into problems early on in the game.

Can someone point out to me what is wrong with the following code?

```
price = float(input("Uh oh, looks like dinner is over. Time to calculate the tip! How much was the bill?"))

price_15 = price * .15

price_20 = price * .20

print("If you're feeling cheap you can give a 15% tip, which would be " + price_15 + "dollars. However, if you want do be a decent human being, you will give a 20% tip, which will set you back " + price_20 + "dollars")
```

**Error:**

```
"/Users/Gabe/Desktop/Python/Challene 2.3.py", line 5, in <module> + price_20 + "dollars") TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you paste the exception traceback into your question?

Comment: Hi there, here is the traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gabe/Desktop/Python/Challene 2.3.py", line 5, in <module>
    + price_20 + "dollars")
TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

Answer (score 2):

You are getting error since you are concatenating float to a string without converting it it to a string. You should convert your float to string or just use commas to separate your arguments to print.

```
print("If you're feeling cheap you can give a 15% tip, which would be " + str(price_15) + "dollars. However, if you want do be a decent human being, you will give a 20% tip, which will set you back " + str(price_20) + "dollars")

print("If you're feeling cheap you can give a 15% tip, which would be " , price_15 , "dollars. However, if you want do be a decent human being, you will give a 20% tip, which will set you back " , price_20 , "dollars")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this alternative format if you think its more readable:

```
print("If you're feeling cheap you can give a 15%% tip, which would be %d dollars. However, if you want do be a decent human being, you will give a 20%% tip, which will set you back %d dollars" % (price_15, price_20))
```

Double percents are to escape the percent character "%%", the "%d" converts your variable to decimal in the string, but as an alternative you can use "%f" to keep it as a float (and not have it rounded to the nearest dollar).
Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations